# use ampscript for URL image on EMAIL TEMPLATE

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, ampscript, email-template

I use an **email template**, and I put an image with a URL on email.

The link contains a query string, something like: https://google.com/?privateId=X

I want to make X to dynamic for each user AND encode - via AMPSCRIPT.

It is possible to use ampscript for URL image on **EMAIL TEMPLATE** ??

And have any other way to do it?‏

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inline AMPscript in that text input for the image url.

Assuming the value you want populated exists in a field on your sendable data extension, the AMPscript below should work.

```
google.com?utm_source=%%=URLEncode(attributeValue('yourDEField'))=%%
```

Just be aware that URLEncode won't prevent PII from showing in your final URL.

Also, since we're talking about utm_source, I'd recommend looking into the [Web Analytics Connector](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_wa_web_analytics_connector.htm&type=5).

Comment: It's worked perfect,  now I success to recognize DE attribute and use Ampscript function.

thank you for your help.